# Android: File upload/download working on emulator but not device

Tags: java, android, file-upload

I have been working on a project that requires files to be uploaded and downloaded to and from the mobile device. The code I have works fine on the emulator (I use genymotion emulator since its faster) but on my personal device, neither feature works. Here is what I use for my upload function:

```
    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    String responseFromServer = "";
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

         dialog.dismiss();

         Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                             +uploadFilePath + "" + curFileName);

         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                Log.e("Upload","Source File not exist :"
                         +uploadFilePath + "" + curFileName);
             }
         });

         return 0;

    }
    else
    {
         try {

               // open a URL connection to the Servlet
             FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
             URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);                

             // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
             conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
             conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
             /********************* Header *****************************************************/
             conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
             conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary); 
             conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", sourceFileUri); 
             /********************  Body *******************************************************/             

             dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
             //
             //     Version data
             /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"version\"" + lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes(VERSION);
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);                 

             /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
             //     End Version data
             //
             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
             dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                       + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

             // create a buffer of  maximum size
             bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

             bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
             buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

             // read file and write it into form...
             bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

             while (bytesRead > 0) {

               dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

              }

             // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


             // Responses from the server (code and message)
             serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
             String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

             Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                     + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

             if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {                                                            
                          Toast.makeText(Tossup.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });               
             }


             //close the streams //
             fileInputStream.close();
             dos.flush();
             dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss(); 
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {                        
                    Toast.makeText(Tossup.this, "MalformedURLException",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss(); 
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("Upload","Shit got real");
                    Toast.makeText(Tossup.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload", "Exception : "
                                             + e.getMessage(), e); 
        } 

         try {
             //inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));


             while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {

                 Log.d("Debug", "Server Response " + str);

             }

         } catch (IOException ioex) {
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
         }

        dialog.dismiss();      
        return serverResponseCode;

     } // End else block
   }
```

I have not been able to trace the source of this problem and StackOverflow has been great at helping me with other issues. Any suggestions appreciated! Thanks.

**Update:** I removed the download code since that was not causing an issue

Comment: when you say it does not work what do you mean? you need to give more information than "it does not work"

Comment: Does the device have an internet connection...?

Comment: What program does the mobile connect with?  Is it on a PC behind a firewall?

Comment: Yes the device has an internet connection. It is connected via wifi and mobile data. I have not tested it without the wifi yet but I will try it now.
Update: The wifi makes no difference.

Comment: By "it does not work" I mean there is no file transfer taking place. The app behaves the way its supposed to but when I check the server to see if the transfer took place, there is no files uploaded.

Comment: which part isn't working, download or upload?

Comment: The upload part. The download is no longer giving me an issue.